# Are the following Twitter quotes from Vox leader true?

Tags: history, politics, spain

Recently [Vox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vox_(political_party)) leader, Santiago Abascal, tweeted that the Spanish government was the worst government in the last 80 years, stating the following facts:

[image]

Translation:

> Never in 80 years has a government destroyed more GDP in Spain
>
> Never in 80 years did public debt and unemployment have increased so much
>
> Never in 80 years has a government caused a greater territorial division or made a pact with all the enemies of Spain
>
> That is the truth that it hurts so much.
>
> We will not be silent.

Tweet is [here](https://twitter.com/Santi_ABASCAL/status/1303599264627654656).

To be fair, GDP, public debt on unemployement should be measured on percentage, not on absolute values, about last fact, it's a bit subjective, but things that contributed to these territorial division and deals can be put for comparison.

As enemies of Spain we can consider the following ones from [El pais newspaper](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Felpais.com%2Fpolitica%2F2019%2F04%2F06%2Factualidad%2F1554567536_180146.html) where it's stated that what would be the enemies of Spain would be politicians from countries who want to separte from Spain who have the intention of declaring independecy for their places breaking the law that considers Spain as whole nation (this would be the best translation of "golpistas separatistas"), communists and the own PSOE.

For those 80 years we can consider also what in the time were considered those "golpistas separatistas", communists, and the own PSOE (which indeed was created before those 80 years).

Are these facts true?

Comment: I edited your question slightly: I added a screenshot of the quote and I translated the entire tweet. If you feel I edited to much then feel free to revert your original post.

Comment: As Spain was not in the world wars I expect the first two to be trivial y true due to covid 19. What is the not inability?

Comment: The third "fact" seems to be split into two, unless I'm missing some context and explanation. For the second part, I'm lost on how to consider it "factually". How to handle the question of who the enemies are? Are Mr. Abascal's opinions of who these enemies are generally well known, and this question changed to ask if a pact was made with them?

Comment: @Dan Getz, according to https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=es&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Felpais.com%2Fpolitica%2F2019%2F04%2F06%2Factualidad%2F1554567536_180146.html, for Abascal, spanish enemies are communists, separatists and the own PSOE.

Comment: OK, so is the fact which you want to investigate "is this the first government in 80 years to make a pact with (all?) groups which *Abascal* considers enemies of Spain"? If so, could you [edit] the question to make that explicitly clear? It might still be hard to answer—one would need to know who from 70 years ago he'd consider enemies of Spain, for example.

Comment: Well, there hasn't been a pandemic on this scale in 100 years. So assigning blame (for its economics consequences) is rather iffy. Trump would say China and WHO are to blame! Some groups in the US even sued China asking it to pay $20 trillion, IIRC

Comment: I think this would be better if it focussed on a single claim, rather than three.

Comment: "it's stated that what would be the enemies of Spain" I don't see that in the link. And do you mean "territorial divisiveness"? "Territorial division" makes it sound like Spain has lost territory.

Answer (score 2):

(Partial answer: I'm leaving the third claim out for now. That one leaves the most to interpretation so I'm not sure this part is even answerable)

Before we get started: 1) there are lots of images 2) Getting data from 1940 is **hard** and I couldn't get what I wanted for all the different claims. As such, I had to limit the period chosen to more recent years for some of those 3) In a way a follow-up: but 1940 was very different from what we have today, which asks why the timescale used (of 80 years) is so big.

**Context of Spanish politics**

The [Franco era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francoist_Spain) started in 1936 and ended in 1975 with his death. Spain became democratic with the [constitution of 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Spain) and since then its legislative power resides with the Parliament, while the executive power is attributed to the prime minister. The current prime minister is [Pedro Sánchez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_S%C3%A1nchez) since 2 June 2018, who is a member of the [PSOE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Socialist_Workers%27_Party), which currently has a majority. This is what Santiago Abascal is referring to when mentioning the current government.

**"Never in 80 years has a government destroyed more GDP in Spain"**

Because the tweet is unclear on this, there are several ways to consider it.

This is the [evolution](https://data.worldbank.org/country/ES) of GDP in absolute value for Spain (in million of current US dollars):
[image: evolution absolute GDP]

And [this](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.KD.ZG?end=2019&locations=ES&start=1961&view=chart) is the evolution of the growth (in %) of the GDP:

[image: evolution growth GDP]

It is also possible to consider the evolution of the GDP per capita, which has an increasing trend, even if it can be argued that Spain does it slightly worse than some of other countries in Western Europe as seen [here](https://ourworldindata.org/economic-growth):

[image: Relative per capita evolution]

For short: in terms of absolute value (globally or per capita), this would clearly be false, but this can be true if picking the percentage based growth or relative GDP compared to some other countries (more comparisons on the website if you are interested).

Overall rating is **mixed**.

**"Never in 80 years did public debt and unemployment have increased so much"**

Public debt first.

Considering debt as a percentage of the GDP, it has varied quite a bit, as per [Business Insider](https://www.businessinsider.com/spains-debt-grows-by-146-billion-2013-2?IR=T):

[image: Spain debt as percent of GDP 1880 and more]

Santiago Abascal is himself sharing a similar image, with added context, showing that several crises result in increases to the GDP, along with some predictions from financial institutions (dating from early 2020, so before the COVID-19 crisis):

[image: Spain debt as percent of GDP with extra context]

Currently, Spain is facing an historically high decrease in GDP of 18.5% (as of July 2020):

[image: RIP Spain GDP 18p5 percent down]

Hence the statement that the government "is destroying the GDP more than has ever been done in the past 80 years". While that is the lowest of the Euro area, the COVID-19 is also an unprecedented economic crisis, driving the overall GDP of the [Euro area down by 12.1%](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/2995521/11156775/2-31072020-BP-EN.pdf/cbe7522c-ebfa-ef08-be60-b1c9d1bd385b#:%7E:text=In%20the%20second%20quarter%202020,statistical%20office%20of%20the%20European):

[image: Decrease GDP Euro area and members]

In absolute value, it has kept increasing:
[image: Absolute Spain HDP 1880 and more]

Which means that both in relative and absolute terms, this part of the claim appears to be **true, but** it has to be put into perspective with the current economical crisis due to COVID-19.

Now for unemployment rate.

The oldest records for unemployment I could find are from [1955](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/29429301.pdf) and can be seen below (continuous line):

[image: Unenmployment rate 1955 and more]

It is true that Spain also appears to be the #1 country in the European Union in unemployment rate as of [June 2020](https://www.statista.com/statistics/268830/unemployment-rate-in-eu-countries/), sitting at 15.6%, however it did reach much worse rates, sitting at about 26% in 2013, so the time period considered is important. A more recent extract to complete the missing years between 1993 and today:

[image: employment rate Spain in percent 1976 and more]

Compared to **1955** which is the earliest reference I could find, this appears to be **true, however** Spain did get higher unemployment rates at times (e.g: 2013).

Comment: It looks like you're interpreting "destroy GDP" as meaning "have GDP decrease on their watch", without any analysis of agency or guilt. I think it might help to be explicit about that, otherwise it might sound like you're drawing a conclusion about agency or guilt. (I know that conflating these two ideas is common politics-speak, but we're not all politicians here.)

Comment: @DanGetz I added context for both the current government (not everyone follows Spain's politics after all :P) and extra context to the changes in GDP both for Spain and the Euro zone as comparison. That should leave less room to misinterpretation. Tell me if I still need to clear things up.

Comment: Ok, re-reading it, it's hard to separate GDP from public debt, since the national debt is very often expressed as a percentage of GDP, so parts 1 & 2 overlap. I'll re-arrange the answer when I can to avoid the repetition tomorrow if I can.

Comment: This answer is really confusing. You have two different images that you refer to as being graphs of GDP in absolute terms. One shows a decrease. The other shows an increase ... and is labeled "dueda". Also, you say the claim is false for absolute GDP, but not percentage change. But shouldn't current absolute numbers be of greater magnitude than current percentage change?